# cakephp 2.7.5 Admin Authentication doesn't authenticate

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I am doing a simple Admin authentication in cakephp 2.7.5  but when I try to login it just doesn't work I've done this several times before in other 2.X versions of cake.. maybe this time Im not doing something quiet well.
here is the code:

App controller:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = ['Paginator', 'Flash', 'Auth' => [
                                 'loginRedirect' => ['controllers' => 'users', 'action' => 'admin_index'],
                                 'logoutRedirect' => ['controllers' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'],
                                 'authError' => 'No puedes accesar esta página',
                                 'authorize' => ['controller'] 
                                ]

                     ];

public function isAuthorized($user){
    return true;
}                    
}
```

In the User Model I have this to hash the password before save.

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()){
    if($this->data['User']['password']){
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

In the User Controller I have the admin_login method:

```
public function admin_login() {

    if($this->request->is('post')){
        if($this->Auth->login()){
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }else{
            $this->Flash->error('La convinacion de usuario/passwowrd es incorrecta.');
        }
    }

}
```

Am I losing something that is making to always throw the error that is in the admin_login method?

If everything is ok how can debug this deeper?

Comment: check your database user password is it hash ?

Comment: Yes @AlimonKarim thee records are hash ... I'm thinking today doing it in a different version maybe.

Comment: Is it working fine now ? If not working may you test it by comment 
'authorize' => ['controller']  this line.

Comment: I checked the hash and the records were hashed also I comment the 'authorize' => ['controller'] out but still the same problem. @AlimonKarim

Comment: This types of problem it may happen for many reason, For example two common mistake 
If your username field not unique (login user name/email) and you have been added same user name several time. If your create your user password before add your auth component.

Comment: I reset the counter in the db delete everything the fields are unique and still the problem.